# News feed APIs for general news

Tags: python, c++, postgresql, feed

I'm building a database + tool that scours news feeds for a certain term. For example "food poisoning from nuts". I want to scour social media sites, news sites, major news aggregators, etc... for that term.

- Question 1: What are some of the news
  aggregator APIs out there?
- Question 2: How Would you go about coding and
  receiving only the latest news from
  the API?

**Edit** Added schematic:
[alt text http://koopics.com/news_parser.jpg](http://koopics.com/news_parser.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you know [Yahoo! Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/)? It's a very flexible feed aggregator, and you can manipulate it using YQL, which is quite powerful **and** has a Python librabry, [python-yql](http://python-yql.org/) :). YQL also has specific "tables" for Twitter and other services and news sources, so, depending on what you want, you might not even need Pipes.

There's a quick example of Pipes + YQL usage at http://blog.ouseful.info/2009/04/27/using-yql-with-yahoo-pipes/ , but you can play around with them at the [YQL Console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/).

So, that's your "Question 1". But, using YQL, "Question 2" (if I understood it correctly) comes naturally, as you use it almost like regular SQL, imposing limits, ordering etc.

Comment: +1 I was looking for something like this :)

Here is an interesting [slide](http://www.slideshare.net/ConSanFrancisco123/yahoo-pipes-middleware-in-the-cloud)

Comment: @Sandy: nice, good reference :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Universtal Feed Parser](http://feedparser.org) ??

Comment: A quick glance on the website says that they haven't been updated since 2007

Comment: But that doesn't do what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Google has a news feeds api but I think it is only for non commercial use
http://www.google.com/support/news/bin/answer.py?answer=59255&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

If you've got monetary support backing your project, Reuters has news data feeds that you can subscribe to on a monthly basis.